# how to count odd and even number with using PROLOG

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

question is:

when we key in mem([1,2,3,4,5]).

we will get the output as bellow:

odd=3

even=2

my coding is like that but cannot run. can help me check where is my mistake??

mem(X,[X|L]).

mem(X,[element|L]):-
    mem([X,L]).

count([],L,L).

count([X|H],L1,L2):-
    write(even),
    X%2=0,nl,
    write(odd),
    X%2>=1,nl,
    count([H],[X|L1],L2).

thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2):

The procedures you have written do two different things and don't actually belong together. `mem/2` is equivalent to the usually builtin `member/2` except that your definition contains an error: in the second clause `element` is an atom instead of a variable so it will not match other elements of the list. The usual definition is

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|L]) :- member(X, L).
```

Note that this definition will not only test if a term is an element of a list but can even be use to generate a list.

What exactly are you trying to do in `count/3`: split the list into two lists, one containing odd and the other containing even; or count the number of odd and even elements? The splitting could be done with something like:

```
count([], [], []).
count([X|L], O, E) :- X rem 2 =/= 0, count(L, [X|O], E).
count([X|L], O, E) :- X rem 2 =:= 0, count(L, O, [X|E]).
```

Note that `=/= /2` and `=:= / 2` force evaluation of arguments as arithmetic expressions while `= /2` attempts to unify its arguments.

Counting the number of odds and evens can be done in a similar fashion, and is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)